# Cabling electric cable (AWG 8) through roof of garage; NEC code?

Tags: wiring, garage, nec

I'm going to run shrouded 8/3 (240V) from the main box on the house through the air to the  garage in order to feed an EVOCHARGE 32A EVSE. Ideally I will come through the roof (flat-roof garage) at a point right above the car and affix a NEMA 6-50 plug at the end.
My question is regarding the entry to the garage. Is it up to NEC code to come through the roof? Or must I run the cable through a wall?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Electric code doesn't really care about holes in the roof .vs. holes in the wall. Service masts that penetrate roofs are very common. Common  sense says *not* creating a potential roof leak (& flat roofs are particularly difficult to seal penetrations on) around the cable entry is wise, since running the cable across the ceiling is the same amount of cable as running it across the roof.

You'll also have to pay attention to minimum clearances above the roof surface and the ground for the cable.

Using a 6-50 plug rather than a hardwired EVSE is not optimal. You'll need an expensive GFCI breaker you would not need for an EVSE, and unlike the GFCI in the EVSE it *won't* self-reset. So if it trips in the night you may have a lot less charge than you expect in the morning.

If you were planning on just dangling the receptacle on the end of the cable, no, that won't fly. You'd need to take the cable somewhere on a fixed support in/on the garage allowing a local disconnect switch for it to be accessible no more than 6 feet 7 inches from the floor to the center of the switch handle in its highest position, BEFORE running off to the ceiling to dangle cordage. Which also suggests wall entry as making a lot more sense.
You'd also need to change from cable to **cordage** on the ceiling and provide strain relief for the cordage, if you intend for it to dangle.

You'll be money ahead if you use 4 or 6 AWG aluminum wire to the garage, even if that means needing to use a sub-panel (if the EVSE specifies copper wires,) as you can use short copper wires from the sub-panel. Copper is rather expensive .vs. aluminum. A sub-panel is also the easy route to the required local disconnect switch.

Comment: Note also that a UF cable by itself isn't legal for use as overhead wiring -- either the OP will need to use an overhead triplex or quadruplex cable, or lash the UF to a messenger wire

Comment: @Ecnerwal, you honor me. My first query is brilliantly answered by one of the kings of this site! <br/> As the EVSE will be the only load on this run from the main  box, why do you recommend 4 or 6 AWG? Would 8 AWG be too small for the sub-panel? To facilitate the adding of another EVSE? Wifey has a  Chevy Volt that is fine with a 120V unit, as its range is only around 40 miles.

Comment: Because I'm suggesting that you use aluminum, and 8 AWG aluminum is not rated for 40A, while either 6 or 4 AWG aluminum is far less expensive than 8 AWG copper (and 6 may be harder to find than 4 in aluminum, so less expensive with excess capacity is fine.) You can waste money on copper if you like, but it's a waste.